# What was the scene Bran Stark was talking about with Sansa?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In **Game of Thrones** season 7 episode 3 *The Queen's Justice*, Bran was talking with Sansa under the a tree in Winterfell.

While explaining to her that he is capable of seeing the past and the present he mentioned a scene about snow and a white dress, Sansa looked shocked and left.

Can anyone please recall what was the scene he was talking about?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bran said:

> It was beautiful that night. Snow falling, just like now.
>   And you were so beautiful in your white wedding dress.

He was describing her wedding to, and subsequent brutal rape by, Ramsay Bolton.

I would post a description of the scene but I can't find one to copy. All the first few pages of Google are taken up by the controversy surrounding it, although the scene itself is not particularly graphic.

Comment: White dress - Checked, Horrible thing happening to Sansa - Checked, Horrible thing happening to her in Stark home - Checked, yup that's the one. +1

Comment: Please can anyone else confirm that this the scene so i can accept the answer? Thanks

Comment: @Mourad see Aegon’s comment above. Plus all the upvotes.

Comment: @Mourad I can confirm that this appears to be the consensus among the podcasts and blogs that I've read/listened to. +1. Example: https://theringer.com/game-of-thrones-season-7-episode-3-queens-justice-recap-a1f28a003ddb "Bran, on the other hand, is barely even human; he’s ascended to a different plane, one where he can’t be bothered with trivial matters like Stark succession and can’t see the casual cruelty in invoking Sansa’s (second) wedding."  It's not from anyone involved with the show, but it shows that this is the consensus interpretation

Comment: The broad consensus on r/GameOfThrones is that this is the referred to scene.  See comments on the [Reddit: S07E03 Discussion Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/6qlhfg/s7e3_postpremiere_discussion_s7e3_the_queens/).  I don't think there's any disagreement or question on this point.

Answer (score -7):

Bran saw his sister getting raped by Ramsey Bolton the legitimized bastard son of Roose Bolton, Lord of the Dreadfort, and the unidentified wife of a miller.

He said that so Sansa could believe he was the Three-eyed raven. As only Theon ( aka dickless Reek), Sansa, the dead good bolton knew bout it.

Comment: I'm not sure that intent was there, other than saying he's sorry she had to go through that.  Bran seems to be losing touch with his humanity, as he transitions more completely into the three-eyed raven.

Comment: @Polo actually I agree with the author here that Bran did intend to prove to Sansa that he can see everything, and did it without much thinking. But since same answer was given three hours before this I downvoted. The part about Bran's intention is better fit as comment, if anything.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that's fair.  I just saw it as more evidence that he was losing touch with the human world. Since neither of us is a greenseer, it will have to remain speculation unless show-runners specifically address it.